# Rescale data with rules

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to rescale data with a certain rule. My data has a range of -finite to +finite. I want to rescale with the following rule:

- for -finite to 0: rescale into -1 to 0
- for 0 to finite: rescale into 0 to 1

For now, my data shows a wrong rescaling...

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler    
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'reviewId': ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'],
        'score': [-1, -5, 0, 3, 38]})
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
df['polarity'] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['score']])
    
print(df)
```

returns

```
  reviewId  score  polarity
0       01     -1 -0.813953
1       02     -5 -1.000000
2       03      0 -0.767442
3       04      3 -0.627907
4       05     38  1.000000
```

Notice how a positive score ("3") is scaled to negative polarity. I tried using MaxAbsScaler but the scale will shift depending on the max value of either one of the positive or negative values. I still want my overall data at "polarity" to be inside the range of -1 to 1 while **maintaining** the max range on the positive and negative values. What should I do with this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this behaviour because [`sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) tries to scale the whole column at once (with the same range for both intervals). One way to avoid/fix that would be to use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and separate the two intervals (negative and positive numbers).

```
m1 = df["score"].lt(0)
m2 = df["score"].ge(0)
​
negScaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 0))
posScaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0 , 1))
​
df = pd.concat([df[m1].assign(polarity = negScaler.fit_transform(df.loc[m1, ["score"]])),
                df[m2].assign(polarity = posScaler.fit_transform(df.loc[m2, ["score"]]))])
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  reviewId  score  polarity
0       01     -1  0.000000
1       02     -5 -1.000000
2       03      0  0.000000
3       04      3  0.078947
4       05     38  1.000000
```